# tlmgr: command not found

Tags: texlive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tlmgr is not accessible after installing TeX Live 2011 on a Ubuntu system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26624/tlmgr-is-not-accessible-after-installing-tex-live-2011-on-a-ubuntu-system)

I just installed TeXlive with the `install-tl-20120117` package.
I expected to be able to use `tlmgr` after the installation but bash came up with the error `tlmgr: command not found`.

I checked whether or not the file `tlmgr.pl` is in `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/scripts/texlive` and it is. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm still trying to learn the ropes here.

**EDIT in Response:** I am running Debian Squeeze on VirtualBox.

```
echo PATH
/home/pjh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/home/pjh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bin:/home/pjh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/home/pjh/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

I think I see the problem, how do I mend this? What should I add to the path? Should I add it in my `.bashrc`?

Comment: It would be helpful to know your OS. Also, have a look at this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26624/tlmgr-is-not-accessible-after-installing-tex-live-2011-on-a-ubuntu-system

Comment: Have you added the newly installed TL to your PATH? Otherwise bash cannot find it. If you have, verify the PATH variable (`echo $PATH`)

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Thanks Marc, I've tried that according to the thread that Psirus posted above. Still gives me the same error, even after reloading. Do I have to dictate the PATH in a config file?

Specifically tlmgr is in /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux. Which really is a symlink to ../../texmf/scripts/texlive/tlmgr.pl

Comment: Marc, what login file are you talking about? .bashrc? .bash_login?

Comment: Add the following two lines to your `~/.bashrc` file. 

`PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/:$PATH`

`export $PATH`

Comment: @recluze The `export` command should be `export PATH`. It should be name of the variable, not its value you want to export.

Comment: `.bashrc` is not always enough, if the path is only added to `.bashrc` then programmes that are started via the menu cannot find TL. In ubuntu I often make sure the TL path is added to the front of the PATH setting within `/etc/environment`, make sure to separate via a ':', then log out and log in again (so the `/etc/environment` is reapplied.

Comment: Okay, I put it into my `.bashrc`. This exact line `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/tlmgr:${PATH}` The same error is appearing.

Comment: Daleif, what do you mean? `cat /etc/environment` came up with a black result. Does that mean I have no environment settings?

Comment: In addition I get this when I export `$PATH` 
`/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/tlmgr:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games': not a valid identifier`

Comment: That just means that Debian does things a little differently, thus I cannot help. I know Ubuntu usually have an `/etc/environment`, but other Linux' may not have. Someone who knows about pure Debian will have to answer.

Comment: you should use `export PATH=TLPATH:$PATH`

Comment: Currently this is what happens when I `echo $PATH` : `/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/tlmgr:/home/pjh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/home/pjh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bin:/home/pjh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/home/pjh/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/tlmgr:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games` A bit redundant, but still an error occurs.

Comment: Thanks again Marc for the help. I don't know what you mean about TeX-sx but I executed the commands. The results are as follows.
`which tlmgr 2>&1` : (blank, no output)

`which latex 2>&1` : `/usr/bin/latex`

`echo ${PATH} 2>&1` : `/home/pjh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/home/pjh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bin:/home/pjh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/home/pjh/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/tlmgr:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

`ls /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux 2>&1` : (too long to list here)

Comment: How do I post all the output? If my hunch is correct, `2>&1` that is storing all the output in a file. Where would the file be located?

Comment: I dont believe `/usr/bin` is before the tlmgr directory. The comment formatting is quite unclear. Here is the echo output again: `echo ${PATH} 2>&1 : /home/pjh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/home/pjh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bin:/home/pjh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/home/pjh/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/tlmgr:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

Comment: Also, the ../i386-linux/ directory has a whole bunch of scripts in it. the `ls` output is quite large.

Comment: Oh! I'm very sorry Marc! I thought they were the same as the last set of instructions! Here they are.

Comment: `which tlmgr 2>&1 : (blank again)`
`which latex 2>&1 : /usr/bin/latex`
`echo ${PATH} 2>&1 : /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/tlmgr:/home/pjh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/home/pjh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bin:/home/pjh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/home/pjh/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`
`ls /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/latex 2>&1 : /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/latex`
`ls /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/tlmgr 2>&1 : /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/tlmgr`

Comment: Usually, you would run `tlmgr` as root.  Which means you will have to add the path to `tlmgr` to the root's path. I have no idea how to do that on Ubuntu, they do not really use a `root` account, and do that `sudo` thing instead.

Comment: same error when running as root

Comment: First method didn't work. Do you know how to install only tlmgr from that huge install package? I installed the whole thing as root. I don't remember having 022 for my umask though.

Comment: Have a look at [http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-998739.html](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-998739.html)

Comment: Please avoid a long list of comments. Consider editing all required information into the question, delete your comments and flag the other ones as outdated. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using a Slackware package see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25388/tlmgr-problems-under-downstream-package-environment

Answer (score 3):

Please see the section on setting the PATH in the [quick install](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) for TL and check the documentation of your OS.

---

UPDATE: The quick install instructions read as follows

> After the installation finishes, you must add the directory of TeX Live binaries to your PATH—except on Windows, where the installer takes care of this. For example: 
>   `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH`
>
> Use the syntax for your shell, your installation directory, and your binary platform name instead of x86_64-linux.
>
> If you have multiple TeX installations on a given machine, you need to change the search path to switch between them. (Except on MacOSX.)